# Check if SSAS Cube is available i.e. processed

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I am looking for a method to check if a cube is accessable i.e. it is processed and not broken.

Example: I got a working cube and i full process a shared dimension so that the cube gets broken.

Is there any mdx or xmla method of finding out what cubes are accessable / processed?

Comment: Why not just run a simple query to the cube and catch any error that might come back?   If no error, then the cube is processed and available.

Answer (score 3):

There is an XMLA command [DISCOVER_XML_METADATA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126291%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) that can return the state of the database (processes/unprocessed) among other properties.  I don't have the best handle on XMLA, so I don't know how to get just the part you need, but this query will return results in the form of XML, and you can parse it from there.

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>
        <Restrictions>
            <RestrictionList>
                <DatabaseID>AdventureWorks2012MD</DatabaseID>
            </RestrictionList>
        </Restrictions>
                <Properties>
                    <PropertyList>
                    </PropertyList>
                </Properties>
            </Discover>
```

This requests gets the properties from the objects related to the SSAS database called AdventureWorks2012M. In the results you will see the following:

```
<Database>
          <Name>AdventureWorks2012MD</Name>
          <ID>AdventureWorks2012MD</ID>
          <CreatedTimestamp>2013-08-01T01:41:10.926667</CreatedTimestamp>
          <LastSchemaUpdate>2013-08-01T01:45:05.91</LastSchemaUpdate>
          <Description />
          <LastProcessed>2013-08-01T01:46:39.713333</LastProcessed>
          <State>Processed</State>
          <LastUpdate>2014-01-07T19:41:45.146667</LastUpdate>
          <AggregationPrefix />
          <Language>1033</Language>
          <Collation>Latin1_General_CI_AS</Collation>
          <Visible>true</Visible>
...
```

You care about `<State>Processed</State>`for that database.  You can also get the state for each of the dimensions and measure groups as well by adding MeasureGroupID or DimensionID to the restrictions list.